# Creating believable build lights

Tags: rendering, lighting

I was wondering how I could create believable building lights. Currently I have plane's with emission shaders that I scattered inside the building but it looks off and doesn't render correctly. Is there a way I could either improve my window light method or a better one?
Currently have:

[image]

render:

[image]